# Failed to install google chrome because libu2f-udev packages not installed - nodejs 10.14.0 docker file

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, google-chrome

Nodejs 10.14.0

docker file e2e code

```
ARG BUILD_ENV

RUN if [ "$BUILD_ENV" = "test" ]  ; then \
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable; \
    fi`

`# unit test stage`
`FROM test as unitTest

ARG TEST_TYPE
RUN if [ "$TEST_TYPE" = "unit" ]  ; then \
    npm run test; \
    fi`

`# e2e test stage`
`FROM test as e2eTest
ARG BUILD_ENV
ARG AD_USERNAME
ARG AD_PASSWORD
ARG SALT
ARG TEST_TYPE
RUN if [ "$TEST_TYPE" = "e2e" ]  ; then \
    npm run e2e; \
    fi
```

log

[image: build log file]

please kindly suggest solution for this issue
i don't want update nodejs version.

suggest solution to run e2e testing